# Days/Hours/Months/Minutes away from Birth in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm having some trouble converting some code from Objective-C to Swift. I'm trying to make a label that tells how old I am. I want to give my birthdate and it'll return days, hours, minutes, seconds on how long I have been living. The code is:

```
@IBAction func birthday(sender:AnyObject){

    var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = 19
    dateComponents.month = 12
    dateComponents.year = 1999

    var calender = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    var birthDate = calender!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
    var currentDate = NSDate.date()

    var durationDateComponents = calender.components(NSCalenderUnit.CalenderUnitDay, fromDate: birthDate!,
        toDate: currentDate,
        options: nil)

    var numberOfDaysFromBirth = durationDateComponents.day

    messageLabel.text = "\(numberOfDaysFromBirth)"
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what happens when you run the code that you posted?

Comment: change NSCalenderUnit.CalenderUnitDay  to NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

Comment: I actually wanted Years, Months, Days, and Seconds. Like how old I am.

Comment: Do you want number of days since your birthday, number of hours since your birth day etc? Like 5586 days, 134074 hours etc.

Comment: I want how old I am. Like in years, 15, months 7, days 3. (the numbers are just an ex)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents.day = 19
dateComponents.month = 12
dateComponents.year = 1999

let birthDate = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!

let durationDateComponents = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!.components( .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour |  .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: birthDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)

let numberOfyearsFromBirth = durationDateComponents.year      // 15
let numberOfMonthsFromBirth = durationDateComponents.month    // 3
let numberOfDaysFromBirth = durationDateComponents.day        // 17
let numberOfHoursFromBirth = durationDateComponents.hour      // 1
let numberOfminutesFromBirth = durationDateComponents.minute  // 28
let numberOfsecondsFromBirth = durationDateComponents.second  // 34
```

Comment: I'm new to swift. So how would I plug this code into a label. Wouldn't I need an IBAction?

Comment: Just creste an IBOutlet for your label. Yes this should go inside your IBAction

Comment: If you want for example the total numbers of hours, you have to pass only the CalendarUnitHour to durationDateComponents

Comment: It tells me to remove the @IBOutlet.

Comment: just add a label to your view. Right click on it and drag a referencing outlet to your ViewController

Comment: It won't show my dayLabel, yearLabel, monthLabel. :(

Comment: I don't know how you want to display your info. You could combine all info in a single label. If you have more than one label you will have to add one outlet for each of them